# How to refer to properties during instantiation of JavaScript array of objects

Tags: javascript

I want to:

1. instantiate a JavaScript array of objects, where objects properties refer to other properties of the object itself, and then
2. use the array to configure click event of a set of buttons.

problems (pls see snippet above):

1. mymessage and myvalue parameters are undefined when anotherfunction() is called
2. when a button of class `myclass*` is clicked x[i].myaction(); is undefined because **at the time the button is clicked**, i evaluates 2

```js
var x = [{
  mymessage: "this is message1",
  myclass: "myclass1",
  myvalue: 10,
  myaction: function() {
    var res = anotherfunction(mymessage, myvalue);
    //do something with res
  }
}, {
  mymessage: "this is message2",
  myclass: "myclass2",
  myvalue: 20,
  myaction: function() {
    res = anotherfunction(mymessage, myvalue);
    //do something else with res
  }
}];

function anotherfunction(m, v) {
  alert(m);
  return v;
}
for (var i = 0, len = x.length; i < len; i++) {
  $('.' + x[i].myclass).click(function() {
    alert(i);
    x[i].myaction();
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myclass1">Click me1</div>
<div class="myclass2">Click me2</div>
```

Comment: As per your modified version of this question. You can take `i` under a closure by the help of an IIFE inside the for loop.

Comment: I understood what you are saying, but unfortunately I'm not so practical with  javascript to effectively use this pattern in above situation :-( please can you give me an example ?

Comment: After the edit it's a duplicate of [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/750486/1529630)

Comment: @Oriol: my question is about referring to other properties of the same object when it is istantiated into an array (as the title try to explain). 
The interesting part of the suggested solution is in my opinion, the use of the 'this' clause. The 
closure is adopted to _consume_ correctly such array, but the 'this' clause is the focus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For re-usability purposes you should in fact use `this` in the object like

```
myaction:  function() {
    anotherfunction(this.mymessage, this.myvalue); 
  }
```

However you should invoke it with the proper context in the callback of the event listener as follows;

```js
var x = {
  mymessage: "this is a message", 
  myclass: "myclass", 
  myvalue: 10,
  myaction:  function() {
    anotherfunction(this.mymessage, this.myvalue); 
  }
};
function anotherfunction(m, v) {
  alert(m);
}
$('.'+x.myclass).click(function(e){x.myaction()})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myclass">Click me</div>
```

So as per the modified version of this question, I believe it's a very good example to demonstrate the re-usability of the `this` in the array of objects. You can safely do as follows;

```js
var x = [{
  mymessage: "this is message1",
  myclass: "myclass1",
  myvalue: 10,
  myaction: function() {
    var res = anotherfunction(this.mymessage, this.myvalue);
    //do something with res
  }
}, {
  mymessage: "this is message2",
  myclass: "myclass2",
  myvalue: 20,
  myaction: function() {
    res = anotherfunction(this.mymessage, this.myvalue);
    //do something else with res
  }
}];

function anotherfunction(m, v) {
  alert(m);
  return v;
}
for (var i = 0, len = x.length; i < len; i++) {
  (function(j){
     $('.' + x[j].myclass).click(function(e) {
                                   alert(j);
                                   x[j].myaction();
                                 });
   })(i);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myclass1">Click me1</div>
<div class="myclass2">Click me2</div>
```

Comment: it gives 'undefined' as result

Comment: @Roberto Vanoli very good point about the `this`. I have overlooked. Now it's ok.

Comment: thanks for advice, I edited my question (but ps note my question is changed from 'instantiating object' to 'instantiating array').

Comment: @Roberto Vanoli I have modified my answer to cover you extended question.

Comment: it works, thankyou! +1 for showing me practical usage of closure :-)

Comment: @Roberto Vanoli You are welcome.. I just had to drive to home from office before replying :)

Answer (score 2):

Simply use `x.mymessage` and `x.myvalue`

```js
var x = {
  mymessage: "this is a message", 
  myclass: "myclass", 
  myvalue: 10,
  myaction:  function() {
    anotherfunction(x.mymessage, x.myvalue); 
  }
};
function anotherfunction(m, v) {
  alert(m);
}
$('.'+x.myclass).click(x.myaction)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myclass">Click me</div>
```

Comment: Following your solution (which actually answers the original question), I realized that my question was oversimplified  and I modified it

Answer (score 1):

Just change it to the following

```js
var x = {
  mymessage: "this is a message",
  myclass: "myclass",
  myvalue: 10,
  myaction: function() {
    anotherfunction(x.mymessage, x.myvalue);
  }
};

function anotherfunction(m, v) {
  alert(m);
}

$('.' + x.myclass).click(x.myaction);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myclass">
  hi
</div>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: pls see my comment to @Oriol response